# Spring Roo+Security: Prevent sniffing in Spring MVC

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-roo

I got a Table `Role`, and i got a table `User` with password and a reference to one role.

My problem is now: Anyone can see and change the User's role.

Is there any way to prevent the access to the `user.password` by Roo-Script via spring-security?

Comment: I think you'd have to modify the `.jspx` and add spring-security tags.

Comment: Thats what i actually did. But if the db-structure changes, i need to repeat those "customizations" for related jspx. Thats why i like to have those changes in the script.

Comment: I will now try to use two different roo webapps for one db, one app for the user, one app for the admins.